# Expectation of conditional KLs

Tags: kullback-leibler

I was reading [how not to train your generative model paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05101). I don’t quite understand how the simplification from equation 4 to equation 5 can be right and based on my calculations it should be wrong. Would anyone mind giving me a hint?
Specifically, if we assume $Q_{x_2}$ is independent of $x_1$ then this equation says that expectation of conditional KLs should equal the KL itself which I think is wrong. Am I making a mistake here?
[image]